# Show that if $(m,n) = 1$, then $(a,mn) = (a,m)(a,n)$, and that $(mx + ny, mn) = (m,y)(n,x)$ for all integers $x,y$

Tags: number-theory

I have gotten that $(a,m)(a,n) | (a,mn)$, but I'm not able to show that it is the greatest such divisor. The proof I have so far is as follows:

Let $d_1 = (a,m)$ and $d_2 = (a,n)$ so $m = l_1d_1$, $n = l_2d_2$, and $a = j_1d_1 = j_2d_2$. Since $(m,n) = 1$, we have
        \begin{align*}
   1 &= mk_1 + nk_2\\
              &= (l_1d_1)k_1 + (l_2d_2)k_2\\
              &= (l_1k_1)d_1 + (l_2k_2)d_2,
  \end{align*}
        so $(d_1, d_2) = 1$. From above $a = j_1d_1 = j_2d_2$, and by Theorem 2.5, $d_1 \mid j_2$ and $d_2 \mid j_1$, so $j_1j_2 \mid a$.

(Where Theorem 2.5 states that if $(a,b) = 1$ and $a \mid bc$, then $a \mid c$)

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535180/show-m-n-1-impliesmxny-mn-m-yn-x-forall-x-y-in-mathbb-z