# Show : $(m,n)=1\implies(mx+ny,mn)=(m,y)(n,x)\;\forall x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, gcd-and-lcm

I figured the best way to go about this would be to show that $(m,y)(n,x) \mid (mx+ny,mn)$ and $(mx+ny,mn) \mid (m,y)(n,x)$. So far I've done the following:

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain, $\exists s,t\in\mathbb Z$ s. t. $(mx+ny,mn)=(mx+ny)s +mnt = mxs+nys+mnt = (m,y)(n,x)\left(\frac{mxs+nys+mnt}{(m,y)(n,x)}\right)$. Thus, $(m,y)(n,x) \mid (mx+ny,mn)$, since $\frac{mxs+nys+mnt}{(m,y)(n,x)} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$\exists a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $(m,y) = ma+yb\;\&\;(n,x) = nc+xd$.

Then, $(m,y)(n,x)= (ma+yb)(nc+xd)=mnac+mxad+nybc+xybd$.

From here I'm not seeing any way to show that $(mx+ny,mn) \mid (m,y)(n,x)$. If anyone could give any hints I would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: may I ask where you found that task? Maybe it would be useful for me as a student as well.(:

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya It's an exercise in LeVeque's "Fundamentals of Number Theory".

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Is this your original problem:https://books.google.hr/books?id=BYvMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=(m,n)+implies+(mx%2Bny,mn)%3D(m,y)(n,x)&source=bl&ots=cp4Z03O00S&sig=ACfU3U3WaA1T7Hzs21eSJffL3MeG4c6now&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFra_TsLrnAhXNl4sKHb9_CKEQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=(m%2Cy)(n%2Cx)&f=false  ?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya No, it's LeVeque "Fundamentals of Number Theory" (1977) Section 2.1 Exercise 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factor of $mn$ is either in $m$ or in $n$, since $(m,n)=1$. If it’s in $m$ and also in $mx+ny$ but not in $n$, then it must be in $y$, and thus also in $(m,y)$. Thus all factors in $(mx+ny,mn)$ are in $(m,y)$. Likewise for $(n,x)$. It follows that $(mx+ny,mn)\mid(m,y)$ and $(mx+ny,mn)\mid(n,x)$, and either is enough to show $(mx+ny,mn)\mid(m,y)(n,x)$.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a little bit? I'm not sure I understand how the result follows

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar: By "result" I meant just the half that you hadn't proved yet. I've edited the answer to make that more explicit. If it's still unclear, please state specifically which part isn't clear to you.

Comment: @BalsamicVinegar Be aware that if you wish to make the above answer rigorous then you need to rigorously justify the various claims about "factors being in" etc, e.g. by using existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations, or related results such as Euclid's Lemma, or gcd poperties,

Answer (score 0):

By Euclid & $\,(\color{#c00}{m,n})=1\!:$  $\ \ \begin{align} \color{#0a0}{(mx\!+\!ny,m)} &=\:\! (\color{#c00}ny,\color{#c00}m) = \color{#0a0}{(y,m)}\\
               (mx\!+\!ny,n)\ &= (\color{#c00}mx,\color{#c00}n) = (x,n) \end{align}$

So $\,(\underbrace{mx\!+\!ny}_{\large a},mn) = 
\underbrace{\color{#0a0}{(y,m)}}_{\large \color{#0a0}{(a,m)}}\underbrace{(x,n)}_{\large (a,n)}\ $ by $\ (a,m)(a,n) = (a(a,\color{#c00}{m,n}),mn) = (a,mn)$

Comment: The first line uses [basic Euclid gcd laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59147/need-help-understanding-euclids-algorithm-to-find-greatest-common-divisor/59200) $\rm\,(a,b) = (\bar a,\,b)\ \ if\ \ a\equiv \bar a\pmod{b}\ \ \ $

Comment: [and also Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/prove-that-if-gcd-a-b-1-then-gcd-ac-b-gcd-c-b/20904#20904) $\rm\,(ad,b) = (d,b)\,\ $ if $\,\rm\ (d,b) = 1\ \ $

Comment: The last line uses basic [gcd "polynomial" arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20904/242), i.e. the gcd associative, commutative and distributive laws.

Comment: **Alternatively** [homogeneous reduce](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3471852/242) to the [case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1977858/242) $\ (m,y)=1=(n,x)\ \ \ $ by cancelling $\,(m,y)(n,x)\  $